# Swift - how to map array to dictionary values?

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I imagine code similar to this:

```
var someDict: [Int:Bool] = { (0...100).map { someInt -> [Int: String] in (someInt:false) } }
```

but it does not work :(

How to properly map array of some value to dictionary?

Comment: It's not clear what the values should be in the returned dictionary, all false?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson ```[1:false, 2:false, 3:false, ........., 100:false]```

Comment: `(0...100).reduce(into: [:]) { $0[$1] = false }`

Comment: An alternative solution `Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: zip(0...100, Array(repeating: false, count: 101)))` which looks better if the range is declared separately `let range = 0...100`,  and then `Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: zip(range, Array(repeating: false, count: range.count)))`

Comment: @JoakimDanielson thanks for your answer. I have created own solution based on your answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The least syntax you can use involves `AnyIterator` to repeat a value indefinitely.

```
Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: zip(0...100, AnyIterator { false }))
```

Comment: I didn’t know about AnyIterator, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `reduce` like this:

```swift
let someDict = (0...100).reduce(into: [Int: Bool]()) { $0[$1] = false }
```

Answer (score -2):

Answer based on answer of **Jessy**, **dillon-mce** and **Joakim Danielson**.Thanks a lot!

It's needed because of horrible syntax of init of set of keys with default values

```
extension Dictionary {
    init<S: Sequence>(_ keys: S, withVal defaultVal: Value) where S.Element == Key {
        self = Dictionary( uniqueKeysWithValues: zip(keys, AnyIterator { defaultVal }) )
    }
}
```

usage:

```
//enum FileFilterMode: CaseIterable
let a = Dictionary(FileFilterMode.allCases, withVal: false)

let b = Dictionary(0...100, withVal: false)
```

## Another way:

```
public extension Sequence {
    func toDict<Key: Hashable, Value>(block: (Element)->(Value)) -> [Key:Value] where Key == Self.Element {
        self.toDict(key: \.self, block: block)
    }
    
    func toDict<Key: Hashable, Value>(key: KeyPath<Element, Key>, block: (Element)->(Value)) -> [Key:Value] {
        var dict: [Key:Value] = [:]
        
        for element in self {
            let key = element[keyPath: key]
            let value = block(element)
            
            dict[key] = value
        }
        
        return dict
    }
}
```

will give you ability to do magic like:

```
// dict's keys 0...100 will have value "false"
let a = (0...100).toDict() { _ in false }

// set of tuples -> dict[ $0.0 : $0.1 ]
let b = setOfTuples.toDict( key: \.0 ) { _ in $0.1 }
```

Comment: This is Objective-C code, written to compile in Swift. You should tag it with Objective-C if you want to use nostalgic-style code.